# How to retrieve objects that have an attached file and order those objects based on a set of pre-ordered values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, paperclip

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2 and Paperclip 2.7.0. I would like to retrieve data from the database where records/objects have an attached file (in my case it is an image file) and order those objects based on a set of pre-ordered values. That is, I have `image_file_name` (handled by the Paperclip gem) and `status` (status can be `published`, `unpublished`, `blocked`) database table columns and I would like that:

1. returned data contains *primarily* records/objects to which is associated an image (maybe this can be handled through the Paperclip gem);
2. that objects retrieved at step #1 are sorted (in order of *importance*) by `blocked`, `unpublished` and then `published` statuses;

More, if returned objects are less than 5, then I would like to "append" to those objects other objects but without caring "filters and ordering" as made in step #1 and #2.

How can I make that?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "caring" a set of pre-ordered values.

Comment: @x1a4 - I mean that I would like order objects (in order of importance) by those having status set to `blocked`, `unpublished` and then `published` (note: I can not use the `ASC` or `DESC` statements for what I am looking for).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is datastore-dependent. If you want to order by specific values of a field in MySQL, for example, you can do:

```
Model.where('image_file_name is not null').order("field('status', 'blocked', 'unpublished', 'published')")
```

Comment: I tried your statement but the `order("field('status', 'blocked', 'unpublished', 'published')")` seems do not work as expected.

Comment: I solved that by using `order("field(status, 'blocked', 'unpublished', 'published')")` (note that status is not quoted by `'`)... and now, if returned objects are less than 5, how to *"append" to those objects other objects but without caring "filters and ordering" as made in step #1 and #2?*

Comment: `collection << Model.limit(5 - collection.length) if collection.length < 5`, or something similar.

Comment: Thanks. I opened another question related to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646877/is-it-possible-to-order-multiple-columns-fields-by-using-the-order-by-field-st.