# Is it possible to order multiple columns by using the `ORDER BY FIELD` statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2 and I would like to know if it is possible to order multiple columns/fields by using the `ORDER BY FIELD` statement (for example, as made in the `Model.order("orders_count, created_at, name, ...")` but for `ORDER BY FIELD`).

If so, how can I "`ORDER BY FIELDS`"?

*P.S.*: As written in a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646374/how-to-retrieve-objects-that-have-an-attached-file-and-order-those-objects-based), in order to order my records relating to *one* column I am using the `Model.order("field(status, 'blocked', 'unpublished', 'published')")` statement.

Comment: You never say if you actually tried it—did you?

Comment: @Andrew Marshall - Yes, I tried `Model.order("field(status, 'blocked', 'unpublished', 'published')")` and it works as expected *but* for *one* column.

Comment: That's not trying something if you expected it to do something different than what you're asking here. Perhaps try combining the two syntaxes and see if that works?

Comment: @Andrew Marshall - ... but, how to combine multiple *columns/fields* in the `order("field(status, 'blocked', 'unpublished', 'published')")` statement as made for `order("orders_count, created_at, name, ...")`?

Comment: Like I said, try combining the two: `order("field(status, ...), orders_count")`. I've no idea if it will work, never tried it and I don't use MySQL so I can't easily test.

Comment: @Andrew Marshall - Maybe the question is not clear. I do not need `order("field(status, ...), orders_count")` but something like `order("field(status, 'a', 'b', 'c'), field(column_one, 'a', 'b', 'c'), field(column_two, ...), ...")`.

Comment: No, it's not clear, you should edit your question to include that and state what happens when you try to run it.